# Facebook’s iOS app: sharing via feed dialogue using a ‘web app’ results in cropped image

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are using a basic feed dialogue to enable sharing on Facebook – title, caption description and image.

The correct image is being picked up, and displays correctly, on desktops, Facebook’s Android app, and the mobile website.

The image (it’s a hand) is being picked by iOS, but it is also being cropped.

The correct image is being picked up, and displays correctly, on desktops, Facebook’s Android app and the mobile website.
[Screenshot - not allowed to post images yet](http://www.hospicecareweek.org.uk/EasysiteWeb/getresource.axd?AssetID=135811)

### Background

- The image is at Facebook’s preferred 1500 x 1500
- The og:image tag we’re using isn’t entirely kosher (I’m working with a preparatory CMS and have limited control) but I have confirmed that the image is being picked up using Facebook’s debugger

### Code

Meta-tag is `<meta name="og:image" content="/EasysiteWeb/getresource.axd?AssetID=135801">`

On-page:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <a onclick="postToFeed(); return false;"><img src="/EasysiteWeb/getresource.axd?AssetID=133763" alt="Share on Facebook"/></a>
    <p id="msg" style="display: none;"></p>

    <script>
//<![!CDATA[    
      FB.init({appId: "app-id-removed-for-posting-to-SO", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: "feed",
          redirect_uri: "http://www.hospicecareweek.org.uk/countmein",
          link: "http://www.hospicecareweek.org.uk/countmein",
          picture: 'http://www.hospicecareweek.org.uk/EasysiteWeb/getresource.axd?AssetID=135801',
          name: "Hospice Care Week",
          caption: "I took the 'Count me in!' pledge for Hospice Care Week",
          description: "Take the ‘Count me in!’ pledge and spread the word about why hospice care counts."
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response["post_id"];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }
 //]]>   
    </script>
```

Comment: We're having the same issue sending posts from the iOS SDK.  Did you ever find a solution? And isn't Stackoverflow Facebook's preferred support platform, and no help from anyone at Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue at the moment. Not sure where you got 1500x1500 from as the recomended size. The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) say

> The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 50px by 50px (though images larger than 200px by 200px are preferred) and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1

We have tried at 90x90 and 200x200 and iPhone app will still crop it. Everywhere else works fine though.